# Is there a way to use mix-blend-mode with html2canvas package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, html2canvas, mix-blend-mode

Does anyone know of a way to use mix-blend-mode with htm2canvas, in the [documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features/) it says that mix-belnd-mode is not supported but I found a package in npm called [html2canvas-add-mix-blend-mode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas-add-mix-blend-mode) but it's not working for me I can't get the mix-blend-mode functionality to work.

I have this function that uses the html2canvas package to convert the div to an image but the mix-blend-mode property is not being rendered.

```
convertToImg(elementId: string): void {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (!element) {
      throw new Error(`Element with id "${elementId}" not found.`);
    }

    // Set DPI (dots per inch) for the canvas
    const dpi = 300;

    // Calculate scale factor based on DPI
    const scaleFactor = dpi / 96;

    // Calculate width and height of canvas in pixels
    const widthPx = element.offsetWidth * scaleFactor;
    const heightPx = element.offsetHeight * scaleFactor;

    // Convert div to canvas with higher DPI
    html2canvas(element, { scale: scaleFactor }).then(canvas => {
      // Convert canvas to image
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      
      // Create a temporary link element
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = imgData;
      link.download = 'filename.png';

      // Trigger a click on the link to start the download
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    });
  }
```

This is what the  looks like in the browser:

[image: This is what the looks like in the browser]

This is what it looks like in the downloaded image:

[image: This is what it looks like in the downloaded image]